# Uploading CSV file to azure table storage does not upload all items

Tags: powershell, csv, azure-table-storage, import-csv

I am trying to upload a CSV file to Azure table storage through powershell script. The CSV has 4776 records but only about 3042 items actually get migrated to Azure table storage. What am i doing wrong/what could be done differently? Here is my code:

```
function Add-Entity()
{
 [CmdletBinding()]

 param
 (
    $table, 
    [string] $partitionKey, 
    [string] $rowKey, 
    [string] $propOne,
    [string] $proptwo

 )
 $assemblySN = $table.CloudTable.GetType().Assembly.FullName
 $entity = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity,$assemblySN" -ArgumentList $partitionKey, $rowKey
 $entity.Properties.Add("FirstProperty",$propOne)
 $entity.Properties.Add("SecondProperty",$propTwo)

 $result = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteAsync((invoke-expression "[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation,$assemblySN]::InsertOrReplace(`$entity)"))
}

Clear-Host
$subscriptionName = "mysubscription" 
$resourceGroupName = "myrg"
$storageAccountName = "mystorage" 
$location = "East US"
$tableName = "mytable"

# Log on to Azure and set the active subscription
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName

# Get the storage key for the storage account
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Value[0]

# Get a storage context
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

# Get a reference to the table
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx 

$csv = Import-CSV <file path>

ForEach ($line in $csv)   
{
 Add-Entity -Table $table -partitionKey $line.Partitionkey -rowKey $line.Rowkey -FirstProperty $line.propOne -SecondProperty $line.proptwo 
}
```

Comment: Is any combination of [PartitionKey + RowKey]  getting repeated in your csv file?

Comment: No there is no replication of [Partitionkey+Rowkey]

Comment: Actually you are right there is....is that why that's happening?

Comment: After removing the replications, i came down to 3449 records. Tried uploading the refined csv again through the script above, but only 3004 records got uploaded. Would you know any other reason why this might be happening?

Comment: In case, of repetitive [PK+RK], Add-Entity will throw (409) conflict. 
I guess, there is some other problem happening so just verify that $csv is having all the record count.

Comment: I cleaned the csv file to not have any kind of replication for [PK+RK] combination. i also added a counter variable in the script and printed it's value to make sure that every line in the CSV is being read by the script, and the counter value was exactly as expected, i.e., the expected number of items. So the script is reading the file fine but somehow not all the items from the file are being uploaded to table storage.

Comment: Have you tried to use ```Insert``` method to upload entity to Azure table storage?

Comment: You mean instead of "Add-Entity" use Insert?

Comment: @RahulKumar Your understanding is right.

Comment: @RahulKumar,  please let us know if the answer works for you.

Comment: AzureRm is deprecated so used Az module instead. Definitely improved migration but there was still inconsistency

Comment: Although this script works perfectly for smaller number of records

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure there is no replication of [Partitionkey+Rowkey] in your .csv file, then the possible reason is that there are some `invalid characters` in your `partition key or row key`. By using your script, the items will not be added into table if it contains invalid chars.

Please check if the following chars are included in your `partition key` or `row key` as per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model?redirectedfrom=MSDN#characters-disallowed-in-key-fields).

The screenshot of the invalid characters:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, we can use the following PowerShell script to import csv file to Azure table storage.

```
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Value[0]
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx 

$CsvContents = Import-Csv -Path $Path
$CsvHeaders = ($CsvContents[0] | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name | Where{$_ -ne "RowKey" -and $_ -ne "PartitionKey"}

Foreach($CsvContent in $CsvContents)
{
    $PartitionKey = $CsvContent.PartitionKey
    $RowKey = $CsvContent.RowKey
    $Entity = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity" "$PartitionKey", "$RowKey"

    Foreach($CsvHeader in $CsvHeaders)
    {
        $Value = $CsvContent.$CsvHeader
        $Entity.Properties.Add($CsvHeader, $Value)
    }
    Write-Verbose "Inserting the entity into table storage."
    $result = $Table.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($Entity))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim can you pls let us know what partitonkey is here in your code snipeet

Answer (score 0):

For posterity... Thanks for this question. It helped me out.

The reason some didn't make it to the storage account could be because the Async task didn't complete yet.

When you call `$table.CloudTable.ExecuteAsync` it returns a Task that has to be awaited. You can await it with `$result.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` I think what is happening is that the last few tasks didn't complete before the process shut down.

Here is my implementation for reference. I could figure out how to do automatic type creation, so I just switched it.

```
function Add-Entity() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        $table, 
        $data
    )

    $assembly = $table.CloudTable.GetType().Assembly.FullName

    $entity = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity,$assembly" -ArgumentList $data.PartitionKey, $data.RowKey
    $data | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ? Name -NotLike '*@*' | ? Name -NE PartitionKey | ? Name -NE RowKey | ? { $data."$($_.Name)@type" } | % {
        $type = $data."$($_.Name)@type"
        $name = $_.Name
        $value = $data.$($_.Name)

        $property = switch ($type) {
            "String" { New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty,$assembly" -ArgumentList ([string]$value) }
            "Boolean" { New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty,$assembly" -ArgumentList ([bool]$value) }
            "DateTime" { New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty,$assembly" -ArgumentList ([DateTime]::Parse($value)) }
            "Double" { New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty,$assembly" -ArgumentList ([Double]$value) }
            "Guid" { New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty,$assembly" -ArgumentList ([Guid]::Parse($value)) }
            "Int32" { New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty,$assembly" -ArgumentList ([Int32]$value) }
            "Int64" { New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty,$assembly" -ArgumentList ([Int64]$value) }
            "Binary" { throw "nope" }
            Default { throw "Unknown Type '$type" }
        }

        $entity.Properties.Add($name, $property)
    }

    $task = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteAsync((Invoke-Expression "[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation,$assembly]::InsertOrReplace(`$entity)"))
    $task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
}
```